# Can't find the Transitive Dependency using maven publication

Tags: android, gradle, transitive-dependency

I have checked multiple questions and have checked the answers as well but those are not working for me.

LibraryA -> LibraryB -> App

I want to access the classes of `LibraryA` from my App and I have added `LibraryA` in `LibraryB` and `LibraryB` is implemented in my `App`.

```
api("com.xyz.abc:LibraryA:1.0.0")
```

I am using the `api` keyword to add the dependency in `LibraryB` and both the libraries are published on `maven` and then I have implemented the `LibraryB` in my app using `implementation` keyword and keeping the `transitive` as `true`.

```
implementation("com.xyz.abc:LibraryB:1.0.0"){
    transitive = true
}
```

After doing all this, when I try to access a class from LibraryA, it gives an error `Unresolved Reference`. But If I try to do the same thing by adding the `LibraryB` as a `module` then all works fine.

Please let me know, what else should I change to make it work for me. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the transitive dependency issue by a small modification. After reading at multiple Stackoverflow questions, I found same thing mentioned everywhere that the dependency should be present in the `pom.xml` file. But for me it was not getting added, even after using `api` to include the dependency the App was not able to access it.
I was adding the dependency in pom file using below code:

```
withXml {
    asNode().appendNode("dependencies").let {
        for (dependency in configurations["implementation"].dependencies) {
            it.appendNode("dependency").apply {
                appendNode("groupId", dependency.group)
                appendNode("artifactId", dependency.name)
                appendNode("version", dependency.version)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was adding only the dependencies that are included using the `implementation` keyword but after adding the below code as well I was able to access the transitive dependency.

```
withXml {
    asNode().appendNode("dependencies").let {
        for (dependency in configurations["api"].dependencies) {
            it.appendNode("dependency").apply {
                appendNode("groupId", dependency.group)
                appendNode("artifactId", dependency.name)
                appendNode("version", dependency.version)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tell us the answer! I'm having a similar issue. Where have you added that code?

Comment: Inside your gradle file, where you have written the code to publish.